# Eclipse REST API connection problems

Tags: java, eclipse, httpurlconnection

On my regular day job I have been requested to update an old program and make it work with an REST API. The program was developed in Eclipse and is having the ‘Connection Refused: connect’ error in the old project but not the new one, the ‘test’ project. Since the company PCs are still on Java 8, I have to use HttpURLConnection class.

The below code was written in the test project and then straight copied to the old program. This is just a simple get method to check the connection to the REST API. What should happen is the server returning a simple J-SON response stating the server name.
Due to company policy, I cannot share more than this. The test project is just a simple Java console application, the ‘old’ program is a Java Swing application. As far as I know, it was originally written in the mid to late 2000s.

```
public void CheckStatus() throws IOException {
    URL requestURL = new URL(#REST API URL#);

    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) requestURL.openConnection();
    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(“GET”);

    //display REST API response in console
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream(), “utf-8”))) {
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String responseLine;
        while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Response.append(responseLine.trim());
        }

        System.out.println(response,toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
#don’t correct the random capitalizations, I’m typing this on my iPad and I don’t know how to turn it off#
```

So this code when called works in my test project but not in the ‘old’ project. Does anyone know why this happens? I have no clue what the problem could be, other than Eclipse being picky of what it wants to do and what not. I would use IntelliJ but it’s not possible (as far as I have looked into it) to import an eclipse project into IntelliJ. I also ruled out any possibilities that the problem is with either: my network, firewall or the server.

Thank you

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean - what happens, what did you expect to happen?

Comment: Eclipse does not run it, the Java VM runs it. So it's unclear why you think the Java IDE you're using even matters here. Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `tuf-8` is not a valid character encoding. Is that a typo only here or there also?